# Woocommerce can't add product to cart in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, woocommerce

After selecting of attributes (product options) on product page, I can't add product to cart. After click on button Add to card, product isn't addeed to cart. Only pop-up with text "Please choose product options…" is displayed.

Problem is only in Internet Explorer.

Any ideas, please? Thank you!

Link:
[link on product page](https://chemineeholz.ch/chemineeholz-kaufen2/ganze-m%C2%B3-raumster/)

[select options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLrFc.png)

[pop up error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqDqH.png)

Comment: Are you sure your theme is compatible with IE? Because when I enter the product page with the inspect tool, a lot of errors show up. "Object doesn't support property or method 'isFinite'", Line 563, appears each time I try to select something on the dropdown menu.

Comment: Please check the tc-final-price.js?ver=1.5 file, after using F12 developer tools to debug your code, it will show this [error "SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'isFinite'"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aSIV.png), please check the JavaScript reference, perhaps you are using some jquery plugin, make sure they are compatible with IE browser?